# applescript to osascript conversion?

Tags: applescript, osascript

I am using max msp to run shell commands, I have been prototyping code in applescript and need them to run in osascript for example -

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to close tab 1 of window 1
```

converts to

```
osascript -e 'tell application \"Google Chrome\" to close tab 1 of window 1'
```

I have converted around 10 commands, but am stuck on the very last one which is

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick/ c:360,550"
    end tell
end tell
```

which I think goes to

```
osascript -e 'tell application \"Google Chrome\" to activate' -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Google Chrome\" to do shell script \"/usr/local/bin/cliclick c:360, 550\"'
```

cliclick lets you use the mouse through shell. http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/. The c is the command identifier for clicking, so at x360 y550

is my syntax correct? it works when I dont include the c identifier.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it gave me this error message:

```
99:151: execution error: System Events got an error: Invalid argument “360,” to command “c”: Expected two coordinates, separated by a comma. Example: “c:123,456” (1)
```

Solution: you have an extra space before the number 550 (c:360, 550) and the second value gets  lost. Remove the space character and it should work (c:360,550)…

Here is a version where I also changed the quoting:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Safari\" to activate" -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Safari\" to do shell script \"/usr/local/bin/cliclick c:360,550\""
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it actually led me on the the real problem which is max msp puts a white space afer a comma. Didnt think this was a problem, but you showed it was!

a backslash sorts this out. I also needed the orignal quoting because of max messing with the formatting

osascript -e 'tell application \"Google Chrome\" to activate' -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Google Chrome\" to do shell script \"/usr/local/bin/cliclick c:360\,550\"'